# Commodore 64 software sales peak year

Tags: history, commodore-64, software, market

Sales of the Commodore 64 itself appear to have peaked (along with sales of 8-bit home computers in general) around 1984, though continued for another decade after that.

I'm curious about sales of software for the machine (all formats: cartridge, disk and tape). I would expect that to peak somewhat later (because people who buy the machine, might keep buying software for several years after that).

Has anyone compiled statistics of sales by year for it? Or for other platforms, that might allow an attempt to extrapolate?

Comment: C64 sales are well documented at [pagetable](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=547). Adding that (especially the [second graph](https://www.pagetable.com/docs/c64_sales/12.png)) might help underline the leading paragraph. (Also, asking as well for other platforms might broaden the question a bit too much - not at least as each had their own region and timeline)

Comment: I think sales figures overall are fine to ask here (although it's quite straightforward to find that information on the web). Going into platforms, software, media type the software was distributed on which might be entirely different per region), and even "other platforms",  makes this way too broad. You're basically asking for Commodore's (and Atari's,... and software vendors') books for all country organisations worldwide over 15 years. You should be narrowing this down.

Comment: @tofro I did narrow it down. The specific question I'm asking is, which year saw the highest sales of Commodore 64 software. If it's straightforward to find that information on the web, can you post a link?

Comment: Now, *that's* not that simple. You *might* possibly find Commodore's sales, but definitly not a full set of ISV's sales. Not even close.

Comment: It's a single sampling of a relative measure only but [in May 1992](https://twitter.com/ChinnyVision/status/1431393686588428289) ELSPA had the C64 as being responsible for 26.1% of all UK software sales; second and third were the Amiga and Spectrum, and the Master System in fourth is the highest-placed console. Which confirmation-biases my prejudice that the sales peak was probably late and based on budget titles, but doesn't actually prove anything of substance.